# Row operations that change similarity class

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ be a matrix. Which [row operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Row_operations) on $A$ do not change its similarity class?

Comment: Adding some zero multiple of any row. Multiplying by the diagonal matrix with entries all 1